# Spring framework has Mockito behaviour when using Mockitio annotation

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockito

i have a code snipet, looking like :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class Testing {

  @Mock
  MyObject sp1;

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    assertNotNull(sp1);
  }
}
```

It is really strange the Spring gives me an instance (not null) of my object (reference sp1), as it is not a @Resource annotation, nor a @Autowired annotation.
In fact, i dit not put the annotation

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

so, the object sp1 should not be instanciated.
But it seeems that Spring has a Mockito behaviour, when
annotation

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
```

is replaced by annotation

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

it is not a big deal, but.. surprising, isn't it ?

question is : why Mock seems to work, as we only have Spring annotations and no Mockitio annotations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@SpringBootTest` is annotated with:

```java
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class})
public @interface SpringBootTest
```

thus has all functionality of `SpringExtension`

Among others, it initializes all test execution listeners specified in file
`URL [jar:file:PATH/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-test/SPRING_BOOT_VERSION/spring-boot-test-SPRING_BOOT_VERSION.jar!/META-INF/spring.factories]`:

```java
# Test Execution Listeners
org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener=\
org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener,\
org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener
```

`MockitoTestExecutionListener` is the one initializing fields annotated with `@Mock`:

```java
public void prepareTestInstance(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    this.initMocks(testContext);
    this.injectFields(testContext);
}
```

This behaviour is also documented in `MockitoTestExecutionListener` javadoc (emphasis mine):

> TestExecutionListener to enable @MockBean and @SpyBean support. **Also triggers MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(Object) when any Mockito annotations used**, primarily to allow @Captor annotations.
> To use the automatic reset support of @MockBean and @SpyBean, configure ResetMocksTestExecutionListener as well.